# Paginated Power BI Report with cascading parameters not working in Power BI Desktop or visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am new to Power BI and Power BI Report Builder.

I have created a Paginated report in power bi report builder. This report has 3 cascading parameters. This paginated report works fine in power bi report builder.
on selecting the first parameter filters the 2nd and 3rd.

Now I am pulling this paginated report into power bi desktop using paginated visual option. In power bi desktop or page, I have created 3 slicers, on add the paginated report. it does not work with slicers are set to All. meaning paginated report does not display the information.

But when one filter option is selected it works well.

can anyone please help.

Thanks, in advance!

Tried to remove slicers, tried to recreate the filters. noting seems to work.
I have only one data set.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the paginated visual? PBI Servive now support’s paginated reports, this visual was a stop gap before they where supported.

Comment: well, the reason I am using it because, it is more convenient to access paginated report in a dashboard rather than navigating to another report. 
In dashboard I have set up navigation to paginated report.